# script error in mozilla firefox when i use tinymce editor

Tags: firefox, tinymce

when i use tinymce editor i get an error like

`A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://rapidsurfing.net/site//jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1`

in mozilla firefox browser i use this code to get tinymce editor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "exact",elements : "ntxtnotefield",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",

    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    // using false to ensure that the default browser settings are used for best Accessibility
    // ACCESSIBILITY SETTINGS
    content_css : false,
    // Use browser preferred colors for dialogs.
    browser_preferred_colors : true,
    detect_highcontrast : true,

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    // Style formats
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
        {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
        {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
        {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
        {title : 'Table styles'},
        {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
    ],

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
```

if any one know how this happen please reply

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest, you set the following

```
plugins : "",
theme_advanced_buttons1: "",
```

If it works then, then you have an error in your plugin or button configuration.